# Word addin has Application.PointsToPixels(), Powerpoint does not, any reason why?

Tags: powerpoint, office-interop

This is a minor pain, as I'm needing to implement my own interface that has a WordApp and a PowerpointApp class implementing an interface which has a PointsToPixels() method.

The WordApp class is already there because I can use the method on _Application to get it: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.pointstopixels(v=office.11).aspx

I'd like to keep the code clean and implement PowerpointApp.PointsToPixels()... but to my diminishing surprise, Powerpoint's "_Application"  class doesn't have it.

The only other way I can see to do it, is to the CreateGraphics() method on a WinForm - which I don't have at this point.

I might be able to work around it in the long run, but it'd be nice to know what is the reason Powerpoint isn't playing ball. It seems to be being difficult for no good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PPT it's called PointsToScreenPixels. Example from PPT VBA Help:

```
With ActiveWindow
    myXparm = .PointsToScreenPixelsX _
        (.Selection.TextRange.BoundWidth)
    myYparm = .PointsToScreenPixelsY _
        (.Selection.TextRange.BoundHeight)
End With
```

That assumes a selected shape that contains text.  A bit impenetrable as a result.

Simpler example that only assumes a selected shape:

```
Debug.Print ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY(ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Top)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I searched (wrongly in hindsight) using the exact same method name and also didn't think to look on the ActiveWindow object either. I actually needed it for measuring the slide width (so ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight was my argument to the PointsToScreenPixels() method